# How much memory leakage (in bytes) can be fatal

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have just used Instruments to record my memory leakage, my app leaks about 2-2.5 mb of memory. I am already starting to fix it but do you think this is a substantial amount of memory leaked? I personally have little experience in this field of using Instruments and measuring memory leakage etc. If not, for next time, what would be a fatal amount. Also, does Instruments record every single memory leak? And if so, then is your app technically perfect (in terms of memory management) if your leakage = 0. 
EDIT:
In Instruments I recorded using memory leakage and I tested every single part of my app, that is how I have recorded the total number of 2-2.5 mb.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory leaks adds up over time so every single byte may be fatal. The only "non-fatal" leakage is the ones done only once during the lifetime of the process.

Comment: Hmmm ok... do you think 2-2.5 mb is a lot? I tested every single part/section of my app

Comment: In what period of time did you leak that amount of memory? Ten seconds? An hour? Two weeks?

Comment: My app isn't very large so about 5 minutes

Comment: If you leaked 2 MB in five minutes, what do you think will happen when someone runs your program for an hour or two? And yes, I think that wasting 2 MB of memory for nothing is a lot in a small application.

Comment: Hmmm... good point. Thanks! Really I just wanted to get some knowledge on what is really bad and really good... not what my app was...

Answer (score 4):

Basically you would want to get rid of any memory you 'own', i.e. have allocated your self.
Should you use alloc/copy/new then this is the case and you should free the resource.

For instance:

```
   NSString *doIOwnThisIWonder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"Nope"];
   NSImage *iOwnThisImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/youownthis.jpg"];
   NSData *perhapsThisData=[iOwnThisImage TIFFRepresentation];
```

'Please do dealloc the image mkay :)

Im lazy so here's a link http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/